# How to evenly space out input boxes from label in html

Tags: html

Im currently making a form in html that includes input forms. In my code I want the input bars to evenly matchup and separate from the labels. I keep just extending the input boxes or unevenly moving them separately. How do I change that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    nav p{
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #d96a5d;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 160px;
        float: left;
        margin: 2px;
    }
    input{
        width: 160px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

</style>
<body>
    <h1>Enter player information</h1>
    Name: <input type="text" id="myText"><div>
    Skill Level: <input type="number"><div>
    Email: <input type="email"><div>
    City: <input type="text"><div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Register</button><div>
    <hr>
    <h2>Players registered</h2>
    <nav>
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Level</p>
        <p>Email</p>
        <p>City</p>
    </nav>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm7N0.png)

Comment: You have some unclosed `div` tags in your code; likely to cause problems

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be a table

```
<table>
   <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="myText"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>field 2</td>
        <td>input 2 etc</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Just add css classes to the td to set the width.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the labels into actual `<label>` elements:

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input name="name" type="text" id="myText"><div>

<label for="skillLevel">Skill Level:</label>
<input name="skillLevel" type="number"><div>

<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input name="email" type="email"><div>

<label name="city">City:</label>
<input name="city" type="text"><div>
```

Notice that I also gave the `input` a `name` tag, as well as the `label` a `for` tag. This tells the browser that they are pairs, as well as what the content is.

Next up all you need to do is a little CSS:

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px; /* Or how ever big a gap you want */
}
```

Hopefully that helps. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css grid` for that

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    nav p{
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #d96a5d;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 160px;
        float: left;
        margin: 2px;
    }
    input{
        width: 160px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    .grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    }

</style>
<body>
    <h1>Enter player information</h1>
    <div class="grid">
      <label>Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="myText">
      <label>Skill Level:</label><input type="number">
      <label>Email:</label><input type="email">
      <label>City:</label><input type="text">
    </div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Register</button>
    <hr>
    <h2>Players registered</h2>
    <nav>
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Level</p>
        <p>Email</p>
        <p>City</p>
    </nav>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ for more

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your code you have some `<div>` tags that are going to cause unexpected results.

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input name="name" type="text" id="myText"><div> <!-- Not correct -->

<label for="skillLevel">Skill Level:</label>
<input name="skillLevel" type="number"><div>

<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input name="email" type="email"><div>
```

As for your layout, you could try css grid https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto ;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
label, input {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align:left;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input name="name" type="text" id="myText">

  <label for="skillLevel">Skill Level:</label>
  <input name="skillLevel" type="number">

  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input name="email" type="email">

  <label name="city">City:</label>
  <input name="city" type="text">
</div>
```